# Swagger does not recognise Fluent Validation of nested objects

Tags: c#, swagger, fluentvalidation

I am using Fluent Validation for my models and I try to map the fields and validation using Swagger.

I have the following model:

```
public abstract class PersonModel
{
    protected PersonModel()
    {
        DetailModel = new DetailModel();
    }

    public DetailModel Details { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerModel : PersonModel
{
    public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }
}

public class DetailModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following validation set with Fluent Validation:

```
public class CustomerModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerModel>
{
    public CustomerModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.DetailModel.FirstName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("FirstName is required");

        RuleFor(x => x.DateJoined)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("DateJoined is required");
    }
}
```

To make Swagger understand Fluent Validation, I used this website as reference:
http://blog.yeticode.co.uk/2015/10/add-fluentvalidation-rules-to-swagger.html

To make Swagger understand new validations, the line below does the magic:

```
schema.required.Add("DateJoined");
```

However, Swagger does not understand child validation such as `FirstName`. If I use data annotation on top of the field `[Required]` in this case, Swagger identifies it correctly.

The problem with the solution provided by this blog is the variable Schema does not contain the navigation to `DetailModel` fields. It only contains the definition for `DetailModel`.

But since `FirstName` is not listed in the schema, I can't add it to the required fields.

Has anybody managed to do that?

Answer (score 1):

1.Create validator for every class:

```
public class CustomerModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerModel>
{
    public CustomerModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.DateJoined)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("DateJoined is required");
    }
}

public class DetailModelValidator : AbstractValidator<DetailModel>
{
    public DetailModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("FirstName is required");
    }
}
```

2. for integrating fluentValidation with swagger use package https://www.nuget.org/packages/MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation/
3. Result:
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cnaN.png)

Answer (score -2):

Since Swagger don't understand "nested" models — make your model flat:

```
public class CustomerModel : PersonModel
{
    public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }
}

public abstract class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**P.S.**

If [this code](http://blog.yeticode.co.uk/2015/10/add-fluentvalidation-rules-to-swagger.html) is the only thing that makes **FluentValidation** work in Swagger - I strongly recommend you to use **DataAnnotations** instead, because it have much more features for validation implementation.

Comment: I only mentioned the line `schema.required.Add("DateJoined");` as a way to facilitate the reading from the blog post. The validation is already in place and this line only makes Swagger recognise that DateJoined is required. The problem I am having is with Nested Objects.

Comment: @GustavoMichel I misunderstood you. Did you tried to add keys "Details.FirstName", "Details.LastName" manually in code? Does validation work after that?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it didn't work because `Details.FirstName` and `Details.LastName` are not in the list of fields `schema.properties`. Only `Details` is in that list. The validation works fine with FluentValidation. My only problem is with Swagger recognising it as a required field.

Comment: do you have any other suggestion for this issue?